# why is ajax not passing input field value to php parser?

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am building an account sign-up page that checks the users email address against the db to ensure said user isn't creating a duplicate account. Using ajax to report if email exists in the db. When typing the email address into the form I always get "email is ok". Meaning that it doesn't exist in the db. However, it is incorrect. If I assign the email as a variable in the php parser like $email="email@exists.com" then it will actually report back the correct result. I'm guessing that the parser isn't getting the value from the form in order to add to the query. Do you know why this isn't working?

```
<input type="text" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off" required />
```

Ajax:

```
    <script>
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "email_check.php";
    var fn = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var pwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

and the parser:

```
<?php

include 'db.php';





$test= $_POST['email'];


  $sql="SELECT email FROM users where email = '$test' LIMIT 1";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
echo 'email is in use.';
exit();

} else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1){
echo 'email is ok';
  exit();
}


  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the email field to your vars when you sent the request, in this line:

```
var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
```

Comment: he also left out the password

Comment: True, but the password wasn't used in the script posted anyway :)

Comment: It looks like an excerpt from a bigger script. he sends firstname and lastname but doesn't use them in the excerpt

Comment: I hadn't added the other fields yet. Just working on email - the var set is e for email. 5th var in the list.

Comment: Yes, e is set, but you haven't added it in this line: var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln; ... "vars" is the only var sent to the email_check scripts, so it is only receiving firstname and lastname in the php code

Comment: Aha! That is what I missed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send email to your parser not firstname/lastname

```
var vars = "email="+e;
```